# Typegoose and Mongoose - Cast to ObjectId failed for value when saving nested list of schema types

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

Getting this error:

```
Competition validation failed: results.0: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ name: 'David'}"
```

Here's the parent:

```
class Competition {
  @prop()
  compName: string
  

  @prop({ ref: () => CompetitionParticipant})
  results: Ref<CompetitionParticipant>[]
}
```

Here's the child:

```
class CompetitionParticipant  {

  @prop()
  name: string
}
```

Here's how it's being called:

```
const CompetitionResults = getModelForClass(Competition)
await new CompetitionResults({compName: 'competition name', results: [{name: 'David'}]}).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you try to save value `{ name: 'David' }` as an reference, which is not supported ([read here for more](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8115)), you need to either provide and valid `_id` (in this case an `ObjectId`), or an instance of `mongoose.Document`

the easiest workaround is to manually loop over the array and save them individually (like in an bulk-insert call, or in an for loop over the array)